# Topped up but no data?

Tags: cellular-data

I topped up my windows Lumia 535 phone and got a text saying I got a big bundle but my data isn't coming through. I've waited nearly 24 hours,tried turning it off and on and just left it alone. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Just make sure you have **Turned off Data roaming** in case your phone shows roaming sign.

Comment: Welcome to Windows Phone. Please mention your phone model and OS version. Have you enabled data in the settings?

Comment: Have you also spoken with your telecom provider?

Comment: Are you sure your data APN settings are correct?